# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] android studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio shows this Failure `[INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`

error occurs while installing the application.
I tried to change min sdk levels, gradle min sdk level but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your min SDK version, and what version of Android is your device running?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 'L'

Comment: Are you using any of the new support libraries announced at IO (e.g. `RecyclerView` or `CardView`)? Do you get the same error if you change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 19?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `<uses-sdk>` line in your manifest matches what's in build.grade, and that your target device/emulator version is in the same range.

Answer (score 0):

Applications that target/compile with the Android L preview currently cannot be run on devices that do not have the L preview.

Change your compile and target versions to API 19 in your build.gradle like so and you should be all set:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```