# Error in Android Studio Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Once I try to run my app in the emulator it sends me this error:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.cerocerouno.safr.aplicacionmisteriosa
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

I try creating another device, and when I run the new one, the same error appears.
And something else I notice that all the emulators have errors, when I touch the screen of
any device I have created it collapses.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cerocerouno.safr.aplicacionmisteriosa"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622255/what-does-failure-install-failed-older-sdk-mean-in-android-studio?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511697/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-android-studio-error?rq=1 and all the other links that appear in the "Related" column on the side of this page. If you are convinced that none of them address your issue, please post your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking the right `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`, make sure you have installed all necessary tools and correct `SDK Platform` for your preferred Android Version in SDK Manager. In *Android Studio* klick on **Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager**. Then install at minimum (for Android 2.2 without emulator):

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools (latest)
- Android 2.2 (API 8)
- SDK Platform
- Google APIs

Also, Change `targetSdkVersion 'L'` to `19` in `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cerocerouno.safr.aplicacionmisteriosa"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 'L'  #change this to 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: I installed everything there is to install.

Comment: I did that, the emulator isn't working anymore, and now there is another error. In the styles.xml file under the directory of values-v21, <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">... 
The parent is in red(An error)...